Irreps of $SU(3)/\mathbb{Z}_3$ from irreps of $SU(3)$
I'm reading Ernest Vinberg's Linear Representations of Groups. He has a nice example linking $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$ by considering the action of $SU(2)$ by conjugation on the set of $2$ by $2$ Hermitian matrices. This action yields the relationship $SU(2)/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong SO(3)$, which is also familiar from physics applications.
I'm curious about understanding the quotient of $SU(3)$ by its center $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

There are representations of $SU(2)$ that are real and others that are pseudoreal (sometimes called quaternionic), but only the real representations of $SU(2)$ correspond to representations of $SO(3)$.
$SU(3)$ has real and complex irreps. Do the real irreps of $SU(3)$ yield representations of $SU(3)/\mathbb{Z}_3$, and do the complex irreps of $SU(3)$ fail to become representations of $SU(3)/\mathbb{Z}_3$?
(If there's a name for $SU(3)/\mathbb{Z}_3$, or if it corresponds to another well-known Lie group, I would appreciate learning it!)

I question the notation $\mathbb{Z}_3$ for the center, since it is neither a cyclic group of order 3 nor the 3-adic integers. Anyway, quotienting a linear group by its center gives the projective version of the group; in this case, the quotients are known as the projective special unitary groups $PSU(2) \cong SO(3)$ and $PSU(3)$ - perhaps this terminology will be helpful in your search.

@arkeet Thanks, the nomenclature of "projective special unitary group" is very useful. Could you clarify your comment on notation? I was under the impression that the center of $SU(3)$ was isomorphic to the cyclic group of three elements; in particular, I thought it was generated by $e^{2 \pi i/3}$ times the identity operator. Are you saying this is not the center, or are you commenting on the use of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ for the cyclic group with three elements?

Sorry, you are right that the center is cyclic of order 3. But I still don't like the notation, since there's no canonical embedding of the integers mod 3 in the group. Just writing $SU(3)/Z(SU(3))$ is fine (or even just $SU(3)/Z$ if you are feeling extra lazy).

This is nitpicky. It's perfectly clear what the OP means by $\mathbb{Z}_3$ in this context.

(All representations are complex and finite-dimensional throughout except for at a handful of points where I talk about real representations.)

In general, if $V$ is an irreducible representation of a group $G$, then by Schur's lemma every element of the center $Z(G)$ acts by a scalar. If we write $\lambda(g)$ for the scalar by which $g \in Z(G)$ acts, then $\lambda : Z(G) \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is a ($1$-dimensional) character of $Z(G)$ which labels irreducibles of $G$ and which is called the central character of $V$.
When $G = SU(3)$ this means that there are three possible central characters, namely, if $g \in Z(SU(3)) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3$ generates the center, there is the trivial central character $\lambda(g) = 1$ and two nontrivial central characters $\lambda(g) = \omega, \omega^2$ where $\omega, \omega^2$ are the two nontrivial third roots of unity. So in this case the irreducibles naturally break up into three classes, rather than two, and one of those classes (trivial central character) corresponds to the irreducible representations of $SU(3)/\mathbb{Z}_3$, which as arkeet says in the comment is the projective special unitary group $PSU(3)$.
The irreducible representations of $SU(3)$ are classified by highest weight theory; explicitly they are parameterized by a pair $(m, n)$ of non-negative integers, and the representation $V_{m, n}$ labeled $(m, n)$ is obtained as a suitable subrepresentation of $V^{\otimes m} \otimes (V^{\ast})^{\otimes n}$ where $V \cong \mathbb{C}^3$ is the vector representation. For example,

$V_{1, 0} \cong V$ is the vector representation; I believe physicists call it $\mathbf{3}$.
$V_{0, 1} \cong V^{\ast}$ is the dual of the vector representation; I believe physicists call it $\overline{\mathbf{3}}$.
$V_{1, 1} \cong \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$ is the (complexified) adjoint representation; I believe physicists call it $\mathbf{8}$.

This description can be used to figure out the central characters: if we choose $g \in Z(SU(3))$ above to be given explicitly by $\text{diag}(\omega, \omega, \omega)$, then the central character of $V$ is $\lambda(g) = \omega$ and the central character of $V^{\ast}$ is $\lambda(g) = \omega^2 = \omega^{-1} = \overline{\omega}$. Moreover, central character is multiplicative with respect to tensor product. It follows that:

Proposition: The central character of $V^{\otimes m} \otimes (V^{\ast})^{\otimes n}$, and hence of $V_{m, n}$, is $\lambda(g) = \omega^{m-n}$. So $V_{m, n}$ descends to an irreducible representation of $PSU(3)$ iff $m \equiv n \bmod 3$.

For example, neither the vector nor the dual vector representations descend to $PSU(3)$, but the adjoint representation does, and so do the symmetric powers $V_{3k, 0} \cong S^{3k}(V)$ and $V_{0, 3k} \cong S^{3k}(V^{\ast})$.

As for the question of real, complex, and quaternionic irreducibles, the character of $V_{m, n}$ is the complex conjugate of the character of $V_{n, m}$, meaning that the character is real (equivalently, the representation is self-dual) iff $m = n$. This means if $m \neq n$ then $V_{m, n}$ is of complex type, and if $m = n$ then $V_{n, n}$ is either real or quaternionic type. So, for example, the vector and dual vector representations are complex, and the adjoint representation is real (because it is the complexification of the real adjoint representation on $\mathfrak{su}(3)$). There is a known dimension formula which gives
$$\dim V_{n, n} = (n+1)^3$$
which can be used to rule out some cases; $V_{n, n}$ can't be quaternionic unless its dimension is even (which happens iff $n$ is odd). Beyond that I don't know which of these representations are quaternionic vs. real, though. Edit: According to the MO link you gave in the comments, $SU(3)$ has no quaternionic representations, so the $V_{n, n}$ are all real. I think this can also be proven more explicitly by showing that they have real forms which can be found inside the symmetric powers $S^n(\mathfrak{su}(3))$ of the real adjoint representation, but I haven't checked this.
So the central character isn't the same as the real / complex / quaternionic classification (although they are related: for $SU(3)$, if an irreducible representation has nontrivial central character it must be complex). The fact that they happen to agree for $SU(2)$ is sort of a coincidence, at least as far as I know.

+1 This is very helpful. I think I'll accept soon, but I might need to think a little more on it. The statement "$m=n \implies$ the character of $V_{n,m}$ is real" is clear, but I'm not yet sure how to go the other direction. For example, the decomposition of $V^{\otimes 3}$ into irreps does contain the adjoint representation, which is real, but probably the specific construction of the irrep $V_{3,0}$ forces it to be complex, so I should probably brush up on that.

P.S. You're right about physicists' nomenclature for $\mathbf{3}$ and the others. Also, it looks like the answers to this question says that it's hard to get quaternionic representations -- only $SU(4k+2)$ for integer $k$ has them (if I follow the answers correctly)

@user196574: I don't know the construction in as much detail as I'd like, but once you know that the characters of $V_{n, m}$ and $V_{m, n}$ are complex conjugates (which doesn't follow from anything I've said so far but I believe follows from the construction, or from computing the highest weight of the dual representation, or in the worst case from the Weyl character formula) then the fact that the $V_{n, m}$ are non-isomorphic irreducibles means it necessarily follows that $V_{n, m}$ has real character iff $m = n$.
